# Nondimensionalization of equation of motion for a magnetic particle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, dimensional-analysis, non-linear-systems

I am trying to make the following equation dimensionless, which describes the motion of a spherical magnetic particle of mass $m$ and radius $a$ in a vessel filled with fluid which has viscosity $\mu$ :
$$m\frac{d^{2}\vec{X}}{dt^{2}} = (\vec{m} \cdot \nabla)\vec{B} + 6\pi \mu a(\vec{u} - \vec{v})$$Where $\vec{X}$ is the vector position of the sphere, $\vec{m}$ is the magnetic dipole moment of the particle, $t$ is time, $\vec{B}$ is an external magnetic field and $\vec{u}$ is the velocity of the fluid. We may assume that $\vec{m} = m\frac{\vec{B}}{|B|}$, i.e the dipole moment aligns with the field, where $m$ is the strength of the magnetic dipole moment. We may also assume that $\nabla B$ is approximately constant over the region, and hence we also have $(\vec{m} \cdot \nabla)\vec{B} \approx const$. The term I am struggling with is the magnetic force term, $(\vec{m} \cdot \nabla)\vec{B}$. I have made the substitutions $\vec{X} = a\vec{X'}$, $t = \frac{a}{U_{0}}t'$ and $\vec{u} = U_{0}\vec{u'}$, where $U_{0}$ is the average fluid velocity over the region, and divided through by $\frac{ma}{U{0}^{2}}$ such that the first and third terms are dimensionless, but I am struggling to make the magnetic force term dimensionless. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean "dimensionless" or "unitless" rather than "zero-dimensional"?  To me, "zero-dimensional" means "point-like", which doesn't make all that much sense in this context.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I mean dimensionless.